# Upper bound of $I(Y; X_{1}, ..., X_{N})$ when we have $I(Y;X_{i}) < B$ for all $i$ $(1 \leq i \leq N)$

Tags: it.information-theory

Let $I(Y;X)$ denote the mutual information between $Y$ and $X$. If we have $I(Y;X_{i}) < B$ for all $i \quad (1 \leq i \leq N)$, could we also get the upper-bound of $I(Y; X_{1}, X_{2},  ..., X_{N})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix any integer $N\ge2$. Let $X:=(X_1,\dots,X_N)$. There is no upper bound $U_N(B)$ on $I(Y;X)$ such that $U_N(B)\to0$ whenever $\max_{i=1}^N I(Y;X_i)< B\downarrow0$. That is, each of the $I(Y;X_i)$'s may be arbitrarily small while $I(Y;X)$ is not small. Informally, each $X_i$ may contain little or no information about the distribution of $Y$, but the information about the distribution of $Y$ contained in all the $X_i$'s together may be essential, even for $N$ as small as $2$.

Indeed, suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_N$ are independent Rademacher random variables (r.v.'s), so that $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=1/2$ for each $i$. Then $Y:=X_1\cdots X_N$ is a Rademacher r.v. independent of each of the $X_i$'s. So, $\max_{i=1}^N I(Y;X_i)=0<B$ for any real $B>0$. However (assuming the natural logarithm in the definition of the mutual information), $I(Y;X)=\ln2\not\to0$ as $B\downarrow0$.

**Details on the equality $I(Y;X)=\ln2$:** Assuming the usual convention $0\ln0:=0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &I(Y;X) \\ 
    &=\sum_{(y,x_1,\dots,x_N)\in\{-1,1\}^{N+1}}
P(Y=y,X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N) \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\times\ln\frac{P(Y=y,X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N)}{P(Y=y)P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N)} \\ 
&=\sum_{(y,x_1,\dots,x_N)\in\{-1,1\}^{N+1}}
P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N) \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\times1(y=x_1\cdots x_N)\,
\ln\frac{P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N)}{\tfrac12\,P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N)} \\  
&=\sum_{(x_1,\dots,x_N)\in\{-1,1\}^N}
P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N) \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\times
\ln\frac{P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N)}{\tfrac12\,P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_N=x_N)}=\ln2.  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your comment !!. But I wonder whether we can say $I(Y;X_1, ..., X_N) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} [H(X_{i} | X_1, X_2, ..., X_{i-1}) - H(X_{i-1} | Y, X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{i-1})] \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N} [H(X_{i}) - H(X_{i} | Y)] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} I(Y; X_{i})$

Comment: @Koukyosyumei : My answer shows that the statement in your comment cannot be true in general: It is possible that $\sum_{i=1}^N I(Y;X_i)=0$ whereas $I(Y;X_1,\dots,X_N)>0$. Are we now ready to wrap up this matter?